# Trying to open specific PDFs using command line, how do I pipe the grep command to start

Tags: windows, command-line, pipe

Complete Noob over here.
I'd like to know how to use pipes to directly open a pdf. All the material I found on various websites didn't quite explain how to exactly achieve this.

What I need to do is to list all files in a folder (the place where I'm working has folders with hundereds to thousands of pdfs in them) filter out a specific one (I know how to do that) and then pass that somehow to Adobe Reader

Here's some pseudocode:

```
C:\Users\Maexle>list files ¦ grep 'some pattern over here' ¦ start "" 'filename grep filtered previously'
```

Sorry if my question is unclear, but I only have a limited english vocabulary.

Cheers,
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a in ("your grep command") do start "" "%%a"
```

would be likely to work.

If you are running the command directly from the prompt, use `%a` in place of `%%a`

I have no idea how *your* particular `grep` works - it may have a target in single or double quotes - would have been good to have a realistic example.

Comment: Thanks. Works just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't really pipe or "grep" in straight Windows cmd line, unless you have other tools installed. Can you use Powershell? That's probably the preferred way, and it comes installed by default in modern Windows.

The following command works for me (but with txt files instead of pdf). The % is short-hand for the ForEach-Object cmdlet and the $_ is shorthand for the value being piped in.

```
powershell Get-ChildItem *.txt | %{ notepad $_}
```

You can use something similar for opening pdf files, although when I tested this I had to use the Start-Process cmdlet (due to spaces in my path I guess).

```
powershell Get-ChildItem *.pdf | %{ Start-Process -FilePath "<path to acrobat exe>" -ArgumentList $_ }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. We have a grep extention for the cmd prompt. I've never used Powershell before but I'll try to fiddle with it.
I'll upvote once/if I get it t work :)